# Как получить информацию c html элемента используя Java ?

Tags: java

Пишу приложение на java. 
Есть некий веб сервис, который генерирует отчеты и размещает их в элементе textarea. Веб сервис так же имеет авторизацию пользователя. Задача вытянуть с этого сервиса эти отчеты. Подскажите как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например можно использовать [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

Если содержимое страницы соответствует XHTML, то можно использовать XPath для доступа к нужным частям документа.